# How to make JSLint to recognize ES6 syntax in IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, jslint

I have seen other questions suggesting putting an option on JSLint, but there is no such option in IntelliJ, as far as I know. All I know is that there's a XML file under the .idea directory, but I don't know which syntax to use.

Comment: IntelliJ's built-in version of JSLint is *ancient*. Can I suggest moving to a more extensive tool such as [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) which has better IntelliJ support?